# Run time error when running macro for multiple find and replace

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

Im getting the following error when trying to run my macro:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Here is the macro:

```
Sub multiFindNReplace()
    Dim myList, myRange
    Set myList = Sheets("Receivable").Range("CN2:CO6") 'two column range where find/replace pairs are
    Set myRange = Sheets("Receivable").Range("A2:BQ1000") 'range to be searched
    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
        myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next cel
End Sub
```

And when I click 'debug', the 3 lines that are highlighted yellow are:

```
myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where did you define and initialize "cel"? Also, what are the data types for myList and myRange?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this and this is the whole code which I got from someone else... Do I need to do something more to define cel?

Comment: Your declaration line should be `Dim myList as Range, myRange as Range, cel as range`  I doubt this is your problem but just a note.

Comment: I'd add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your module, to make sure you declare all variables.  Then, edit per @ScottCraner.

Comment: I did what Scott Craner and Bruce Wayne suggested, now I get "compile error: named argument not found" and the debugger shows "SearchFormat:=" highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the value in `myList` column 1 may not exist in `myRange`

You can test for this before trying to replace something that does not exist and move on if it's not found. See below. *(I removed the `SearchFormat` arguments since they don't seem to apply here (and defaults are fine))*

```
Option Explicit

Sub multiFindNReplace()

    Dim myList as Range, myRange as Range, cel as Range

    Set myList = Sheets("Receivable").Range("CN2:CO6") 'two column range where find/replace pairs are
    Set myRange = Sheets("Receivable").Range("A2:BQ1000") 'range to be searched

    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells

        Dim rngFound as Range
        Set rngFound = myRange.Find(cel.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

        If not rngFound is Nothing Then 

            myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True

        End If

    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually also removed the search format arguments a few minutes ago and got it working using the original code I posted in addition to using the new declaration line... Now I'm just trying to figure out how to get it to work on cells that dont **ONLY** contain what I'm searching for. If I'm seaching for "A" it will change a cell that contains "A" but it wont change the "A" in a cell that contains "AB"

Comment: I got it, changed xlWhole to xlPart. Thanks for your help.